# Image display issue for blob images

Tags: image, coldfusion, resize, coldfusion-11

**Update:**

Images were saved in SQL server as blob type. Images get truncated if you do not check the option for blob in CF admin "Data sources" section..[Option to check blob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HutDU.png)

It does not seem like CF is doing this. I see images truncated in Production that are just fine in Development.

---

I am using ColdFusion 11 in Development and Production. I can successfully upload images from my local dev with out any truncation. However, when I upload from the Production server, I am getting following error in FF, and the uploaded image is half of the original image:

> "Image corrupt or truncated. URI in this note truncated due to
>   length."

This is my code I am using html form.

```
<cffile
    action="upload"
    filefield="IMAGE"
    destination="#application.ImagePath#"
    nameconflict="makeunique"
    accept = "image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/png,image/x-png,image/jpg"
 />

<cfimage name="uploadedImage"
    source="#application.ImagePath#\#file.serverFile#" >

<cfimage source="#uploadedImage#" action="resize" width="1350" 
    height="590"
    destination="#application.ImagePath#\#file.serverFile#" 
    overwrite="yes">
<cffile
    action="readbinary"
    file="#application.ImagePath##CFFILE.ServerFile#"
    variable="binPhoto" 
/>  

<cffile
    action="delete"
    file="#application.ImagePath##CFFILE.ServerFile#"
/>
```

Comment: (Edit) Are you getting a *browser* error or server side error? If is a browser error, could you please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37903755/edit) to include A) The code displaying the image and B) the full error message? (Nothing to do with this issue, but `file` is deprecated. Instead use the `cffile` scope, or a named "result" variable).

Comment: I got this figured out. I do not have blob option turned on in SQL server

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  That is a common gotcha with blobs. Though for next time, please include the actual code *causing* the error ie display code.  Knowing blobs were involved would have made the issue more obvious ;-)  If you think the solution would be helpful to someone else, update your question with the query/display code (so the answer makes sense). Then post the solution as a separate "answer", and close out the thread.  Otherwise, delete the thread.

Comment: If you are new to Stack Overflow, it uses a Q&A format (question and answer). To post the solution, please use the "Post Your Answer" button. (Answering your own question is allowed on S.O.)  Also, it would help others to update the question with the actual cfquery throwing the error. (The `<cffile>` code above really is not relevant here ;-).